# How to create new conditional column for last month value using power query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

```
# This is what i do in DAX and its work

lm_cohort = 
    CALCULATE(MAX(Dim__cluster[cohort]), ALLEXCEPT(Dim__cluster, Dim__cluster[membership_id]), PREVIOUSMONTH(Dim__cluster[month_id]))
```

[image]

I didn't find anyway using power query or advanced editor.

Can someone help me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Custom Column with:

```
let
 tbl = #"Your previous step", // change this to match your previous step in the query
 mID = [membership_id],
 prevM = Date.AddMonths([month_id], -1),
 find = Table.SelectRows(tbl, each [membership_id] = mID and [month_id] = prevM),
 result = List.First(find[cohort])
in
 result
```

Full example query that you can paste into a new query:

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSs9MK6lKTFTSUTIw1HVJTdY1MgaynROLSxNz9D3z0opSgdyw1KJKBY/M9Awg2zG5JLMsVSlWB02vf3IJRK9PfmViTmZxCZH6/PLLyLbTsTSdLDuDUwuI0hcLAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [membership_id = _t, month_id = _t, cohort = _t, basket_size_cluster = _t, #"active/inactive" = _t]),
  #"Changed column type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"membership_id", type text}, {"month_id", type date}, {"cohort", type text}, {"basket_size_cluster", type text}, {"active/inactive", type text}}, "en-US"),
  #"Added custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed column type", "lm_cohort", each 
    let
      tbl = #"Changed column type",
      mID = [membership_id],
      prevM = Date.AddMonths([month_id], -1),
      find = Table.SelectRows(tbl, each [membership_id] = mID and [month_id] = prevM),
      result = List.First(find[cohort])
    in
      result)
in
  #"Added custom"
```